# Che differenza c'è tra "non ci siamo mai detti le parole" e "non ci abbiamo mai detto le parole"?

Tags: meaning, difference, auxiliary-verb, past-participle, grammatical-analysis

Sono tutte e due frasi corrette? Oppure cambia anche il significato? Non capisco la prima frase, che dovrebbe essere una costruzione passiva. Potete fare, per favore, un'analisi grammaticale della prima frase?

Grazie!

Comment: Benvenuto/a su Italian.SE!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solo la prima frase è corretta, la seconda è sbagliata.

Semplificando molto, in italiano esistono tre [diatesi](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/diatesi_(Enciclopedia-dell%27Italiano)/): attiva, passiva e riflessiva. Le regole dell'uso della diatesi riflessiva sono leggermente complicate (vedi per esempio l'articolo presso l'[Enciclopedia dell'italiano Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/verbi-riflessivi_%28Enciclopedia-dell%27Italiano%29/)), ma in questo caso si tratta chiaramente di un *riflessivo reciproco*. Dall'Enciclopedia dell'Italiano:

> Nel riflessivo reciproco (diretto o indiretto) il verbo è (di)transitivo. I suoi argomenti agiscono l’uno sull’altro e sono contemporaneamente agente e paziente (benefattivo nei riflessivi reciproci indiretti) l’uno rispetto all’altro: per es., detestarsi, influenzarsi.
>
> In questi casi l’idea della reciprocità è resa esplicita da avverbi quali *a vicenda*, *reciprocamente*, *l’un l’altro*, nei casi in cui il costrutto può avere sia interpretazione riflessiva sia reciproca (Cordin 1988: 603):
>
> (7) quei due si detestano (a vicenda / l’un l’altro)
>
> (8) Mario e Giovanna si sono regalati reciprocamente un viaggio in Marocco.

Di conseguenza l'ausiliare da utilizzare in questo caso è l'ausiliare della diatesi riflessiva, cioè *essere*, e la seconda frase è sbagliata.

L'unico modo in cui la seconda frase può essere corretta è se si tratta di una forma attiva. In questo caso, *ci* non può essere un pronome riflessivo, ma dev'essere un avverbio di luogo (per cui la frase significherebbe *non abbiamo mai detto le parole in quel posto*)